# Not able to run CLI/SHELL for influxdb docker image

Tags: ubuntu, docker, influxdb

I am giving a try to influx db for a small project. Followed the following link to run docker image on ubuntu 17.04. https://hub.docker.com/_/influxdb/

Started the container using following command and influxdb started perfectly.

```
foo@ubuntu:~/software/influxdb$sudo docker run -p 8086:8`enter code here`086 -v $PWD:/var/lib/influxdb influxdb
```

When executing following command for CLI/SHELL getting error.

```
foo@ubuntu:~/software/influxdb$ sudo docker run --rm --link=influxdb -it influxdb influx -host influxdb
docker: Error response from daemon: Cannot link to a non running container: /influxdb AS /epic_lumiere/influxdb.

foo@ubuntu:~/software/influxdb$ sudo docker exec -it influxdb influx
Error response from daemon: Container c04706b2bbcd5cfa70f66d156f1b8f513f2214d5bf2f7a0dd3ff517b45774e08 is not running
```

Note: influxdb is running fine, and i am able to connect to it using http.

```
foo@ubuntu:~/software/influxdb$ sudo docker run -p 8086:8086 -v $PWD:/var/lib/influxdb influxdb


[I] 2018-02-21T08:21:12Z InfluxDB starting, version 1.4.3, branch 1.4,     commit 60d27e6995558f38a39e90b35a92cbac080310a3
[I] 2018-02-21T08:21:12Z Go version go1.9.2, GOMAXPROCS set to 4
[I] 2018-02-21T08:21:12Z Using configuration at: /etc/influxdb/influxdb.conf
[I] 2018-02-21T08:21:12Z Using data dir: /var/lib/influxdb/data service=store
[I] 2018-02-21T08:21:12Z reading file /var/lib/influxdb/wal/_internal/monitor/1/_00001.wal, size 877606 engine=tsm1 service=cacheloader
[I] 2018-02-21T08:21:12Z reading file /var/lib/influxdb/wal/_internal/monitor/1/_00002.wal, size 0 engine=tsm1 service=cacheloader
[I] 2018-02-21T08:21:12Z /var/lib/influxdb/data/_internal/monitor/1 opened in 88.565658ms service=store
[I] 2018-02-21T08:21:12Z opened service service=subscriber
[I] 2018-02-21T08:21:12Z Starting monitor system service=monitor
[I] 2018-02-21T08:21:12Z 'build' registered for diagnostics monitoring service=monitor
[I] 2018-02-21T08:21:12Z 'runtime' registered for diagnostics monitoring service=monitor
[I] 2018-02-21T08:21:12Z 'network' registered for diagnostics monitoring service=monitor
[I] 2018-02-21T08:21:12Z 'system' registered for diagnostics monitoring service=monitor
[I] 2018-02-21T08:21:12Z Starting precreation service with check interval of 10m0s, advance period of 30m0s service=shard-precreation
[I] 2018-02-21T08:21:12Z Starting snapshot service service=snapshot
[I] 2018-02-21T08:21:12Z Starting continuous query service service=continuous_querier
[I] 2018-02-21T08:21:12Z Starting HTTP service service=httpd
[I] 2018-02-21T08:21:12Z Authentication enabled:false service=httpd
[I] 2018-02-21T08:21:12Z Listening on HTTP:[::]:8086 service=httpd
[I] 2018-02-21T08:21:12Z Starting retention policy enforcement service with check interval of 30m0s service=retention
[I] 2018-02-21T08:21:12Z Listening for signals
[I] 2018-02-21T08:21:12Z Sending usage statistics to usage.influxdata.com
[I] 2018-02-21T08:21:12Z Storing statistics in database '_internal' retention policy 'monitor', at interval 10s service=monitor
[httpd] 172.17.0.1 - - [21/Feb/2018:08:22:28 +0000] "HEAD /ping HTTP/1.1" 204 0 "-" "curl/7.52.1" 5ad8ee44-16e0-11e8-8001-000000000000 3075
[I] 2018-02-21T08:51:12Z Retention policy shard deletion check commencing. service=retention
[I] 2018-02-21T09:13:48Z SHOW DATABASES service=query
[httpd] 172.17.0.1 - - [21/Feb/2018:09:13:48 +0000] "GET /query?q=show+databases HTTP/1.1" 200 109 "-" "curl/7.52.1" 86ae24be-16e7-11e8-8002-000000000000 3423
```

Thanks in advance, for any help.

```
foo@ubuntu:~/software/influxdb$ sudo docker ps -a | grep influxdb
[sudo] password for foo: 
5e73d087fc19        influxdb            "/entrypoint.sh infl…"   About an hour ago   Created                                            sleepy_lumiere
18acacfc6377        influxdb            "/entrypoint.sh infl…"   5 days ago          Up 5 days                 0.0.0.0:8086->8086/tcp   loving_benz
97d935acebd7        influxdb            "/entrypoint.sh infl…"   5 days ago          Exited (255) 5 days ago   0.0.0.0:8086->8086/tcp   happy_agnesi
5d6491f9f143        influxdb            "/entrypoint.sh infl…"   5 days ago          Exited (255) 5 days ago   0.0.0.0:8086->8086/tcp   wizardly_bhabha
7d30f3891672        influxdb            "/entrypoint.sh infl…"   7 days ago          Exited (0) 6 days ago                              elastic_booth
2a5451537561        influxdb            "/entrypoint.sh infl…"   7 days ago          Exited (255) 7 days ago   0.0.0.0:8086->8086/tcp   flamboyant_ride6
646581f7bcf9        influxdb            "/entrypoint.sh infl…"   7 days ago          Exited (0) 7 days ago                              competent_blackwell
c04706b2bbcd        influxdb            "/entrypoint.sh infl…"   8 days ago          Created                                            influxdb
97fcd152046d        influxdb            "/entrypoint.sh infl…"   8 days ago          Exited (0) 7 days ago                              flamboyant_tereshkova
ee562bceaa51        influxdb            "/entrypoint.sh infl…"   8 days ago          Exited (0) 8 days ago                              objective_cray
```

Problem is solved, following are the command i need to execute to run  cli/shell for influxdb (Thanks to rajiv)

```
foo@ubuntu:~/software/influxdb$sudosudo docker run --rm --link=<container_name> -it influxdb influx -host <container_name>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to run this with the actual name of influxdb container i.e loving_benz. Below command should work.

> sudo docker run --rm --link=loving_benz -it influxdb influx -host
>   loving_benz

Comment: Didn't work. Getting following error.


    foo@ubuntu:~/software/influxdb$ sudo docker run --name influxdb -p 8086:8086 -v $PWD:/var/lib/influxdb influxdb
    docker: Error response from daemon: Conflict. The container name "/influxdb" is already in use by container "c04706b2bbcd5cfa70f66d156f1b8f513f2214d5bf2f7a0dd3ff517b45774e08". You have to remove (or rename) that container to be able to reuse that name.

Comment: Looks like your influxdb container is not running. Can you post the logs using command 'docker logs influxdb'?

Comment: Hi, Sorry to say this command is not printing anything for me. But if i hit http api's of influx db for any query, i will get result. Which means influx db is running fine. as i am able to execute queries and get the results using api's.

Comment: Please share the output of 'docker ps -a | grep influxdb'

Comment: Added the output you asked in question itself.

Comment: You have to pass the actual container name loving_benz to access the CLI/SHELL . Use the command 'sudo docker run --rm --link=loving_benz -it influxdb influx -host influxdb'.

Comment: foo@ubuntu:~$ sudo docker run --rm --link=loving_benz -it influxdb influx -host localhost
Failed to connect to http://localhost:8086: Get http://localhost:8086/ping: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8086: getsockopt: connection refused
Please check your connection settings and ensure 'influxd' is running.
.

~~~ But my db is running and ping is working "$ curl -sl -I localhost:8086/ping
HTTP/1.1 204 No Content
Content-Type: application/json
Request-Id: faa6050e-1fb9-11e8-966d-000000000000
X-Influxdb-Build: OSS
X-Influxdb-Version: 1.4.3
X-Request-Id: faa6...
Date: Sun, 04 Mar 2018 14:40:26 GMT
"

Comment: You have to use the container name as -host option. Run the command 'sudo docker run --rm --link=loving_benz -it influxdb influx -host loving_benz'

Comment: Great to hear that. I have updated the final steps in the answer section. Please give your feedback.